# .NET Runtime Event Id 5000

Tags: .net, exception

Does anyone know how to decipher a .NET Runtime [Event Id 5000](http://eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=5000&eventno=7334&source=.NET%20Runtime%202.0%20Error%20Reporting&phase=1) error? I have run that's logged as:

```
P1:  <assembly name>,exe
P2:  2.1.4.1 (assembly version)
P3:  48b2b154
P4:  System
P5:  2.0.0.0
P6:  471ebf0d
P7:  575
P8:  1d
P9:  n3ctrye2kn3c34sgl4zqyrbfte4m13nb
P10: NIL
```

I assume those are either the register values of the CLR VM, or parameter calls to a function? The Google hits I've come across seem to have an exception type in there somewhere - giving some sort of clue. From this one, I can recognize one of my assembly names and versions (P1 and P2), and perhaps a FX assembly and version (P4 and P5). The rest, I'm having trouble figuring out.

Oddly enough, the seemingly random "n3ctry..." string actually does come up with [hits on Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=n3ctrye2kn3c34sgl4zqyrbfte4m13nb&btnG=Search), but not enough for me to make any sense of what it may be. A temp file maybe? A ClickOnce isolated storage path? Are the algorithms predictable enough to expect a good number of conflicts?

Thoughts are welcome - as this particular app is in an environment that makes production debugging pretty difficult.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply an unhandled exception occurring inside your application.  Instrument the application to log more information than what .NET does - even if you could get information on all the Px lines, it may not be enough for you to debug it.

This [wandering through the wilderness](http://www.julmar.com/blog/mark/PermaLink,guid,f733e261-5d39-4ca1-be1a-c422f3cf1f1b.aspx) blog entry has good advice on how to address this.  In short, you need to hook the [appdomain's unhandled exception event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(VS.80).aspx).

```
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledException...
```

then log more information some place like the event log.  The [KB article 911816](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=911816) about this event for ASP.NET has sample code for dumping the exception information to the event log that might help.

Comment: Click once run in multiple app domains so I assume you have one for your app domain, but not the main app domain.  Are you running with full permissions so you can enumerate and hook all the app domains?